# -[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue] Crash

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have this method on Objective-C:

```
- (id)userInfoForSelectedIndex {
    if(selectedIndex < self.buttons.count)
     return self.buttons[selectedIndex].userInfo;
    else
     return nil;
}
```

**.userInfo** should be an MyEnum value

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MyEnum) {
   ValueA      = 0,
   ValueB
};
```

And the app crashed when I tried to run (Objective-C code):

```
- (SomeEnum)activeFilter {
   return [[MyClass userInfoForSelectedIndex] unsignedIntegerValue];
}
```

with this output on the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800025ac10'
```

Any suggestion of what is causing the crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Enum was provided by some Swift function.

The problem was an error on the type during the swift - obj-c interoperability. I solved it using the **rawValue** on the swift function instead of the enum itself.

When the code run on **Obj-C** it will use the value as an UInt instead some wrong swift value type caused by casting the EnumType (MyEnum) to id return type on **userInfoForSelectedIndex**.